# Python - Calling lines from a text file to compile a pattern search of a second file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Forgive me if this is asked and answered.  If so, chalk it up to my being new to programming and not knowing enough to search properly.

I have a need to read in a file containing a series of several hundred phrases, such as names or email addresses, one per line, to be used as part of a compiled search term - pattern = re.search(name).  The 'pattern' variable will be used to search another file of over 5 million lines to identify and extract select fields from relevant lines.

The text of the name file being read in for variable would be in the format of:

```
John\n
Bill\n
Harry@helpme.com\n
Sally\n
```

So far I have the below code which does not error out, but also does not process and close out.  If I pass the names manually using slightly different code with a sys.argv[1], everything works fine. The code (which should be) in bold is the area I am having problems with - starting at "lines = open...."

```
import sys
import re
import csv
import os

searchdata = open("reallybigfile", "r")
Certfile = csv.writer(open('Certfile.csv', 'ab'), delimiter=',')

**lines = open("Filewithnames.txt", 'r')
while True:
    for line in lines:
        line.rstrip('\n')
        lines.seek(0)
        for nam in lines:
             pat = re.compile(nam)**

for f in searchdata.readlines():
    if pat.search(f):
        fields = f.strip().split(',') 
        Certfile.writerow([nam, fields[3], fields[4]])
lines.close()
```

The code at the bottom (starting "for f in searchdata.readlines():") locates, extracts and writes the fields fine.  I have been unable to find a way to read in the Filewithnames.txt file and have it use each line.   It either hangs, as with this code, or it reads all lines of the file to the last line and returns data only for the last line, e.g. 'Sally'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a couple lines of sample from each input file?

Comment: The input file would be similar to what is above, but generally firstname.lastname.  A sample line of the reallybig file may look look like 2014-06-03,2017-06-02,12345678901234567,5336789,40803A,"ACTIVE","bb-klm-ssl-Unc-1y-v6","AE","cn=JOHN L. MELLON  123420,uid=john.mellon@helpme.com,ou=people,o=internal,dc=helpme,dc=com"  but the lines can vary.  The consistency is in the search term we are looking for being present.  It just does not always fit the profile shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while True` is an infinite loop, and there is no way to break out of it that I can see. That will definitely cause the program to continue to run forever and not throw an error.

Remove the `while True` line and de-indent that loop's code, and see what happens.

EDIT:

I have resolved a few issues, as commented, but I will leave you to figure out the precise regex you need to accomplish your goal.

```
import sys
import re
import csv
import os

searchdata = open("c:\\dev\\in\\1.txt", "r")
# Certfile = csv.writer(open('c:\\dev\\Certfile.csv', 'ab'), delimiter=',') #moved to later to ensure the file will be closed

lines = open("c:\\dev\\in\\2.txt", 'r')
pats = []   # An array of patterns
for line in lines:
    line.rstrip()
    lines.seek(0)
    # Add additional conditioning/escaping of input here.
    for nam in lines:
         pats.append(re.compile(nam))

with open('c:\\dev\\Certfile.csv', 'ab') as outfile:    #This line opens the file
    Certfile = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')       #This line interprets the output into CSV
    for f in searchdata.readlines():
        for pat in pats:    #A loop for processing all of the patterns
            if pat.search(f) is not None:
                fields = f.strip().split(',') 
                Certfile.writerow([pat.pattern, fields[3], fields[4]])
lines.close()
searchdata.close()
```

First of all, make sure to close all the files, including your output file.
As stated before, the `while True` loop was causing you to run infinitely.
You need a regex or set of regexes to cover all of your possible "names." The code is simpler to do a set of regexes, so that is what I have done here. This may not be the most efficient. This includes a loop for processing all of the patterns.

I believe you need additional parsing of the input file to give you clean regular expressions. I have left some space for you to do that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Removing the 'while True' stopped the hang, but it reverts to only providing the responsive data to the last line of the file.

Comment: The line with pat= should do an append instead of a simple assign. There may be another bug or two.

Comment: My ignorance shows here.  I am not following the append guidance.   The re.compile is needed to create the regular expression out of the name / email address. That is used against the reallybigfile, to locate the reference which is in one of many fields per line and part of a long alpha-numeric-special character string.  How or what would I be appending?   Thanks.

Comment: So you need a regular expression with the set of names from "Filewithnames.txt". And you need to compare that regular expression (i.e. that set of names) with each line in "reallybigfile". At present, you are generating many individual regular expressions from the set in "filewithnames.txt" and overwriting it.

Comment: I had the epiphany on the append early this morning then realized I was still wrong when I read your code.  The append works fine from the read in, and yes, I need to clean my input some.   Thank you.